# socket connection fails in php script while it works in terminal

Tags: php, sockets, ssl

That is the script I have

```
<?php
    $timeout = 10;
    $target = "tls://testbed-epp.nominet.org.uk:700";

    $result = stream_socket_client($target, $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT);
    if ($result === False) {
        throw new Exception("Error connecting to $target: $errstr (code $errno)");

    }

    echo "Connected";
```

And it throws an exception

```
Error connecting to tls://testbed-epp.nominet.org.uk:700: (code 0)
```

There is also a warning

```
WARNING: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
```

At the same time running

```
 openssl s_client -connect testbed-epp.nominet.org.uk:700
```

in a terminal connects flawlessly.

Any ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$result = stream_socket_client("testbed-epp.nominet.org.uk:700", $errno, $errstr);
```

EDIT: also you can setup secure connection via **stream_socket_enable_crypto()** function, but you should note that it must be used AFTER initialization of socket connection.

Comment: Strangely it works without specifying the protocol. The problem is I can not edit that file because it is a third-party library. Besides that the same script works on another server just fine so there is something with the server configuration I suppose. My original concern was that in runs through VPN client installed on a VM node in a remote server. But as it turns out that's not the issue

Answer (score 1):

Well, i tested your code on my apache server, and it is working fine. Can you check your apache configs. In the configs there is a parameter called `"Registered Stream Socket Transports "`. Just check if `tls` exists as a value over there, else there is some other problem, but it definitely isn't your script

Comment: Doing phpinfo() shows that Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls

Comment: ok, this is strange but i noticed in your error above the `$errstr` is empty. You should have something. I tried changing the port and it gave me `connection refused`. Similarly, you should have something for this error

Comment: The thing is it is empty and the error code is 0. On my original script error logging catches a warning - WARNING: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto. I updated the question. Probably the reason warning was not shown in the test script is the fact I ran it through command line

Comment: do you have `openssl`  extension enabled in your configs?
I just realised i have openssl support enabled on apache.

Comment: It is enabled. If you are talking about httpd.conf LoadModule

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeout =- 10;
          ^----
```

You're setting `$timeout` to be negative 10 seconds. e.g. you're killing the connection attempt before it can EVER get started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was a typo and in the original script it is positive. So this is not the reason I am afraid

Comment: And the variable is not used, a hardcoded timeout of `30` is instead.